# Are the punishments for embarrassing someone only for public embarrassment, or does this also apply to one who shames another chronically in private?

Tags: sources-mekorot

Are the punishments for embarrassing someone only for public embarrassment, or does this also apply to one who shames another chronically in private?

All of the meforshim I've seen (like the Rambam) seem to say that this is in public, but does chronic ona'as devarim in private qualify? Would love a source if this is the case.

Comment: Why specifically chronically? BTW, it is always prohibited as onas devarim, just there is no punishment for that, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

The prohibition of embarrassing someone applies in private too. However, the specific punishment of losing the portion in the world to come is only for public embarrassment.

The Rambam (Deos 6:8) writes:

> המוכיח את חבירו תחלה לא ידבר לו קשות עד שיכלימנו שנאמר ולא תשא עליו
> חטא כך אמרו חכמים יכול אתה מוכיחו ופניו משתנות ת"ל ולא תשא עליו חטא
> **מכאן שאסור לאדם להכלים את ישראל וכל שכן ברבים** אף על פי שהמכלים את
> חבירו אינו לוקה עליו עון גדול הוא כך אמרו חכמים המלבין פני חבירו ברבים
> אין לו חלק לעולם הבא לפיכך צריך אדם להזהר שלא לבייש חבירו ברבים בין
> קטן בין גדול ולא יקרא לו בשם שהוא בוש ממנו ולא יספר לפניו דבר שהוא בוש
> ממנו
>
> He who rebukes a friend, at the beginning, no hard words should be
> used against him to shame him, for it is said: "And thou shalt bear no
> sin upon him" (Lev. 19.17). Thus did the wise men say: "Understand it
> not by rebuking him thou mayest cause his countenance to change
> expression; for, it is said: 'And thou shalt bear no sin upon him'"
> (Ibid.; Arakin, 16b); **herefrom we learn that it is forbidden to put an
> Israelite to shame, needless to say publicly.** Although he who does put
> his fellow to shame is not flogged, it is a grievous sin. Even so did
> the wise men say: "He who publicly puts his fellow's countenance to
> shame has no share in the world to come" (Pirke Abot, 3.15). A man is,
> therefore obliged to guard himself against putting his fellow to shame
> publicly, regardless of whether he be young or old; not to call him by
> a name of which he feels ashamed, nor tell aught in his presence of
> which he is ashamed. (Sefaria translation)

The Rambam clearly explains the prohibition in general terms, and further extrapolates the severity of doing so publicly.

The Chafetz Chaim (Pesicha, Laavin 14) codifies this prohibition, and highlights the difference between private and public shaming:

> וְאִם גִּנָּהוּ כָּל כָּךְ בַּדְּבָרִים הַנַּ"ל וְכַיּוֹצֵא בָּהֶם
> בְּפָנָיו וּבִפְנֵי אֲחֵרִים, עַד שֶׁנִּשְׁתַּנָּה פָּנָיו עַל
> יְדֵי זֶה, עוֹבֵר גַּם כֵּן עַל לָאו (ויקרא י"ט י"ז) דְּ"לֹא תִשָּׂא
> עָלָיו חֵטְא" שֶׁהִזְהִירָה הַתּוֹרָה בָּזֶה, **שֶׁלֹּא לְבַיֵּשׁ אֶת
> חֲבֵרוֹ יִשְׂרָאֵל אֲפִלּוּ בִּמְקוֹם הַתּוֹכָחָה וּבֵינוֹ לְבֵין
> עַצְמוֹ**, דְּהַיְנוּ שֶּׁלֹּא לְדַבֵּר אִתּוֹ קָשׁוֹת עַד
> שֶׁיַּכְלִימֶנּוּ, **קַל וָחֹמֶר שֶׁלֹּא בִּמְקוֹם הַתּוֹכָחָה וּבִפְנֵי
> אֲחֵרִים.**
>
> **וְכָל זֶה שֶּׁלֹּא הָיָה בָּרַבִּים, אֲבָל אִם הִלְבִּין אֶת
> פָּנָיו בָּרַבִּים, כְּבָר כְּרָתוּהוּ רַזַ"ל מֵעוֹלָם הַבָּא**
> וְאָמְרוּ: הַמַלְבִּין אֶת פְּנֵי חְבֵרוֹ בָּרַבִּים אֵין לוֹ חֵלֶק
> לָעוֹלָם הַבָּא.